# Where to store user's access token

Tags: api, local-storage, access-token, slack-api

I'm currently working on integration with Slack. The goal is to give a user the ability to share information using the Slack account right from our platform.
Since Slack uses OAuth2, we gain the access token on the backend (because of the app secret) and use it on the frontend. On the client-side, the token is stored in local storage.

Is it okay to store such tokens in local storage? The access does not expire itself, however can be revoked. P.S. the Slack application itself stores tokens in local storage.